# Python script invocation weirdness on Windows (aka why PATH did not get inherited?)

Tags: python, windows, activestate

I've encountered a behavior I did not expect when executing the following Python script (I named it repro.py):

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH'].replace(';', '\n')
```

If invoked by `python repro.py`, I get this:

```
C:\Python26\
C:\Python26\Scripts
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
```

When I invoke it by entering `repro.py` on the command prompt, I get this result:

```
C:\Python26\
```

Clearly `repro.py` inherits different environments depending on how it was started. When started as the first arg to python interpreter, it behaves more like I'd expect. On the other hand, when it gets started by whatever process that automatically figures out what program to use when "opening" .py files, it inherits *really* austere environment. It begins to smell like some sort of security feature.

Is there any way to make both ways of invocation behave the same, preferably equivalent to `python repro.py`?
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Version info: `ActivePython 2.6.5.12 (ActiveState Software Inc.)` on Windows7.

Comment: I see the expected behavior on both Vista and 7 with AS Python 2.6, all path items no matter how I run it, so it seems like a setup issue on your machine. The difference you're seeing may possibly be caused by how .py files are associated but I can't think how at the moment. Try it on another machine if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is bizarre. I'm running the standard python 2.7 from python.org on windows 7, and both invocations print the full PATH, as expected.

It may be a bug, or "feature" in ActivePython. :)

Although, are you opening them both in the same command prompt window? Perhaps your path really had been changed?

Comment: when I get a moment, I shall try your theory RE: ActivePython by installing vanilla Python from python.org